# MySQL LIMIT in a Correllated Subquery

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group, correlated-subquery

I have a correlated subquery that will return a list of quantities, but I need the highest quantity, and only the highest. So I tried to introduce an order by and a LIMIT of 1 to achieve this, but MySQL throws an error stating it doesn't yet support limits in subqueries. Any thoughts on how to work around this?

```
SELECT Product.Name, ProductOption.Name, a.Qty, a.Price, SheetSize.UpgradeCost,
        FinishType.Name, FinishOption.Name, FinishTierPrice.Qty, FinishTierPrice.Price
FROM `Product`
    JOIN `ProductOption`
        ON Product.idProduct = ProductOption.Product_idProduct
    JOIN `ProductOptionTier` AS a
        ON a.ProductOption_idProductOption = ProductOption.idProductOption
    JOIN `PaperSize`
        ON PaperSize.idPaperSize = ProductOption.PaperSize_idPaperSize
    JOIN `SheetSize`
        ON SheetSize.PaperSize_idPaperSize = PaperSize.idPaperSize
    JOIN `FinishOption`
        ON FinishOption.Product_idProduct = Product.idProduct
    JOIN `FinishType`
        ON FinishType.idFinishType = FinishOption.Finishtype_idFinishType
    JOIN `FinishTierPrice`
        ON FinishTierPrice.FinishOption_idFinishOption = FinishOption.idFinishOption
WHERE Product.idProduct = 1
    AND FinishTierPrice.idFinishTierPrice IN (SELECT FinishTierPrice.idFinishTierPrice
                                              FROM `FinishTierPrice` 
                                              WHERE FinishTierPrice.Qty <= a.Qty
                                              ORDER BY a.Qty DESC
                                              LIMIT 1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a variation of the `greatest-n-per-group` problem that comes up frequently.

You want the single row form FinishTierPrice (call it `p1`), matching the FinishOption and with the greatest Qty, but still less than or equal to the Qty of the ProductOptionTier.

One way to do this is to try to match a second row (`p2`) from FinishTierPrice that would have the same FinishOption and a greater Qty.  If no such row exists (use an outer join and test that it's NULL), then the row found by `p1` is the greatest.

```
SELECT Product.Name, ProductOption.Name, a.Qty, a.Price, SheetSize.UpgradeCost,
        FinishType.Name, FinishOption.Name, FinishTierPrice.Qty, FinishTierPrice.Price
FROM `Product`
    JOIN `ProductOption`
        ON Product.idProduct = ProductOption.Product_idProduct
    JOIN `ProductOptionTier` AS a
        ON a.ProductOption_idProductOption = ProductOption.idProductOption
    JOIN `PaperSize`
        ON PaperSize.idPaperSize = ProductOption.PaperSize_idPaperSize
    JOIN `SheetSize`
        ON SheetSize.PaperSize_idPaperSize = PaperSize.idPaperSize
    JOIN `FinishOption`
        ON FinishOption.Product_idProduct = Product.idProduct
    JOIN `FinishType`
        ON FinishType.idFinishType = FinishOption.Finishtype_idFinishType
    JOIN `FinishTierPrice` AS p1
        ON p1.FinishOption_idFinishOption = FinishOption.idFinishOption
        AND p1.Qty <= a.Qty
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `FinishTierPrice` AS p2
        ON p2.FinishOption_idFinishOption = FinishOption.idFinishOption
        AND p2.Qty <= a.Qty AND (p2.Qty > p1.Qty OR p2.Qty = p1.Qty 
            AND p2.idFinishTierPrice > p1.idFinishTierPrice)
WHERE Product.idProduct = 1
    AND p2.idFinishTierPrice IS NULL
```